# How can I implement a function which checks if the given username is an alphanumerical starting with a lowercase letter in erlang?

Tags: erlang

How can I implement a function which checks if the given username is an alphanumerical starting with a lowercase letter (Erlang atom)?

This function is the equivalent in JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script language="javascript">
function verif(){
var x = document.getElementById('username').value;
if (x.length == 1 && x.charAt(x.length-1)== "'")
{
  alert("Please provide a valid user name. The user name has to be a alphanumerical starting with a lowercase letter !");
  return false;
}
else if  (x[0] == "'" && x.charAt(x.length - 1) =="'" )
{
return true;
}
else 
{
  var b = x[0] === x[0].toUpperCase();
    if  (b == true )
    {
          alert("Please provide a valid user name. The user name has to be a alphanumerical starting with a lowercase letter !");
          return false;
    }
 }  
}
```

Comment: Its a RefactorERL task, and I am trying to implement a new web interface for refactorERL public server, this question is related to the registration form. the user name has to be a alphanumerical starting with a lowercase letter.
I checked :
case is_atom(Username) of 
.........
but always goes to `false`
I tried to print the user name and this is what I got :
the username is : "foudelsalhi"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need the username to be a non-empty string, where the first element is a lower-case letter, and the rest are letters or numbers.

Let's start by matching out the first letter:

```
is_valid_username([First | Rest]) ->
```

Check if it's a lower-case letter:

```
    $a =< First andalso First =< $z
```

And check if the rest of the characters are alphanumeric:

```
        andalso lists:all(fun is_alphanumeric/1, Rest);
```

Finally add a function clause for the empty string:

```
is_valid_username("") ->
    false.
```

Now we just need to implement the function `is_alphanumeric/1`, which checks a single character:

```
is_alphanumeric(C) ->
    $A =< C andalso C =< $Z orelse
    $a =< C andalso C =< $z orelse
    $0 =< C andalso C =< $9.
```